# поле поиска при нажатии на картинку

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

[image: weather]

Помогите сверстать, никак не выходит. 
При нажатии на лупу , логотип SimpleWeather уезжал вправо, а на его место появлялось поле поиска. Спасибо

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title>SimpleWeather</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" rel=""></script> 
  </head>
  <body> 
    <header> 
      <div class="simple"> 
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
        <div class="search-input"></div> 
        <div class="search">
          <img src="images/search.png" alt="search">
        </div> 
      </div> 
      <h1 id="city">Lviv</h1>
      <small id="country">Ukraine, UA</small> 
    </header>
```

Comment: Круто конечно, но не покажете код для редакции?

Comment: //html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>SimpleWeather</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" rel=""></script>
</head>
 <body>
  <header>
   <div class="simple">
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
    <div class="search-input"></div>
    <div class="search"><img src="images/search.png" alt="search"></div>
   </div>
      <h1 id="city">Lviv</h1>
      <small id="country">Ukraine, UA</small>
  </header>

Comment: Добавьте код в шапку поста. Выделите HTML, CSS, JS код и вам обязательно помогут.

Comment: //css

}
.location {
 margin-top: 30px;
}
#city{
 font-size: 70px;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: Oswald-Regular; 
 padding-left: 55px;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

#country{
 font-size: 25px;
 color: white;
 font-family: Oswald-Regular;
 padding-left: 55px;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.search-input{
 height: 50px;
 width: 200px;
 background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
 right: -198px;
 top:13px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.search {
 margin-top: -10px;
 float:right;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

Comment: Госпади, вы за сутки этот вопрос третий раз задаете (правда в этот третий раз хоть html появился). И всегда ждете, чтобы вам сделали, а вы забрали готовое и ушли. Жаль те предыдущие точно такие же тему удалили вы сами - чтоб ткнуть в них обратно вас как шкодливого котёнка. Раз не выходит, значит есть полный код того, что вы делаете. Выложите пожалуйста полный код того, что вы сделали и что не получается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 -webkit-transition:.4s;
}
.search-pole{
 width:40px;
 position:relative;
 margin:30px 100px;
 background:lightblue;
 border-radius:14px;
}
.search-pole:after{
 content:'';
 display:block;
 clear:both;
}
.images{
 width:40px;
 height:40px;
}
.form{
 width:0;
 height:0;
 margin:10px 0;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 display:none;
}
.form input{
 display:block;
 height:16px;
 position:relative;
}
.form button {
 position:absolute;
 left:150px;
 top:4px;
 outline:none;
 border:none;
}
.form img{
 width:16px;
 height:12px;
 
}
.search-pole .images,.form{
 float:left;
}
.search-pole:hover{
 width:230px;
}
.search-pole:hover .form{
 display:block;
 width:260px;
 height:40px;
 left:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-pole">
   <div class="images">
     <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/30_Free_Black_ToolBar_Icons/40/Black_Search.png" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="form">
  <form action="#" method="">
    <input type="" placeholder="Наберите и нажмите ENTER" />
  <button> 
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/harwen/simple/128/RUN-icon.png" />
  </button>
  </form>
  </div>
  
  </div>
```

Это приблизительная вёрстка - для примера . Вы так хотели ?

Comment: Любите за других работу выполнять?)

Comment: мне это не сложно - 9 лет за плечами - минуту потратил на это

Comment: Т.е. на работе с каждым годом вы требуете меньше платить вам, потому что это плёвое же дело год от года?....Но дело не в том сложно вам или нет, а совсем в другом

Comment: это на работе - а здесь смотря что , могу сделать могу нет